# fable: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `arima`

Tags: r, time-series, forecast, fable-r

Here is my code:

```
library(fpp3)
val <- seq(1,100,1)
time <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),  by = "day", length.out =  100 )
df <- data.frame(val = val, time = time)
fit <- df %>% as_tsibble(., index = time) %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(val))

fc<- fit %>% forecast(h=7)
```

It generates:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `arima`.
x Input must be a vector, not a `fcdist` object.
i Input `arima` is `(function (object, ...) ...`.
```

This is essentially the same as in this [example](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/fable/). What am I missing? I already double checked for fat fingers error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine with `fableTools` `‘0.2.1’` and `fpp3` `0.3`

```
fit %>%
     forecast(h = 7)
# A fable: 7 x 4 [1D]
# Key:     .model [1]
#  .model time             val .mean
#  <chr>  <date>        <dist> <dbl>
#1 arima  2010-04-11 N(100, 1)   100
#2 arima  2010-04-12 N(100, 2)   100
#3 arima  2010-04-13 N(100, 3)   100
#4 arima  2010-04-14 N(100, 4)   100
#5 arima  2010-04-15 N(100, 5)   100
#6 arima  2010-04-16 N(100, 6)   100
#7 arima  2010-04-17 N(100, 7)   100
```

Comment: What is your version of `fpp3`?

Comment: It is 0.3.  Can you check that

Comment: I used `dplyr` `1.0.1` on `R 4.0.2`

Comment: My `dplyr` is `1.0.0` trying to udpate

Comment: I updated my R to 4.0.2 version and it solved all the problems

Comment: @user1700890 i also had problems with `fable` in the past.  I think it is still under development

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a NAMESPACE problem. E.g some packages loaded, that masked the `fable`, `fabletools` functions.

Can easily happen in this case, since you loaded `fable`, `fabletools` only with a `library(fpp3)` call.
You did not call with e.g. `fable::forecast` in your code and you also did not load `library(fable)` before.

When you just load `library(fpp3)` it will not mask functions for `fable`.

E.g.

```
library(forecast)
library(fpp3)
```

In this case, your code will call `forecast::forecast()`. The `library(fpp3)` call does not mask the `forecast`, `model`,`ARIMA` functions of other packages. So if you had `forecast` loaded in your Namespace before, you will in this case call `forecast::forecast()` instead of `fable::forecast()`.

If you call

```
library("fpp3")
library("forecast")
```

You get:

```
Attache Paket: ‘forecast’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:fabletools’:
   accuracy, forecast
```

So maybe it would have worked, if you would have called `library(fable)`, `library(fabletools)` before, since this would have made sure, similar named functions are masked. Or used `fabletools::`. This might also be why it worked after an update .. since the namespace was then free of other functions and loaded packages.